# Names into categories from Sheet1 to Sheet2 with large blank spaces

Tags: excel

I am attempting to use Excel to help me see which classes are in common among my students.  I created a sheet that has a list of their names in the first column; the following columns have every possible class that the students are taking. In this sheet, I simply put an x in the column for the class that they are taking.

On sheet 2, I want to have the same column of classes with a list of students below each class that shows everyone that is going to take that same class.

Right now I am doing this by using this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTA(Sheet1!B2)=1,Sheet1!A2,"")
```

This gives me a list, but obviously there are a lot of blank spaces.  How might I do this so that each list starts from the first row, without leaving any spaces?

Comment: I've created something similar on Web Application: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35731/29140

Answer (score 0):

In your second sheet, copy all and Paste Special Values over the top. Replace nothing with say "", then replace "" with nothing. Go To Special and select Blanks. Delete with shift cell up.